# Is there any way that I can set value from tagModel used in ngx-chips in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

HTML code:

```
 <tag-input
class="martop20 tag-adder width100 heightauto"
[onAdding]="onAdding"
(onAdd)="addInternalDomain($event)"
type="text"
```

> 

Ts code:

```
addInternalDomain(tagText: TagModel) {
 console.log(tagText.value)
}
```

Getting error : Property 'value' does not exist on type 'TagModel'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the `onAdd($event: string)` output emits a string. So this should works:

```js
addInternalDomain(tagText: string) {
 console.log(tagText)
}
```

Comment: If I apply that change then I am getting error.

Argument of type 'TagModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'TagModelClass' is not assignable to type 'string'.
302     (onAdd)="addInternalDomain($event)"

Comment: TagModel object response is of type { display: 'display', value: 124242,}
Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips#properties-optional